# How to imrove an algorithm filtering list by two conditions?

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin

I have a class with two enum fields representating type and charging status

```
enum class StationType {
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2,
    FAST,
}

enum class ChargingEntityStatus {
    AVAILABLE, // the best option
    CHARGING,
    RESERVED,
    UNAVAILABLE, // the worst option
    OCCUPIED
}

data class Station(
    val stationId: Long,
    val status: ChargingEntityStatus,
    val type: StationType,
)
```

And I need to convert a list of these objects in that way: there can be two or more stations with the same type but different statuses values, but I need a list containing only one each type but with the best status value as the result and Available ones should come first.

For example, if I have a list of stations

```
listOf(
    Station(1, StationType.TYPE_1, ChargingEntityStatus.CHARGING), 
    Station(9, StationType.TYPE_2, ChargingEntityStatus.UNAVAILABLE),
    Station(3, StationType.TYPE_1, ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE), 
    Station(7, StationType.FAST, ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE)
)
```

that should convert to

```
listOf(
    Station(3, StationType.TYPE_1, ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE), 
    Station(7, StationType.FAST, ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE),
    Station(9, StationType.TYPE_2, ChargingEntityStatus.UNAVAILABLE),
)
```

because I need only one station of each type(like in a set), but also the AVAILABLE ones on the first places.

I've made this kind of algorithm, but I don't understand how to improve it:

```
if (stations.isNotEmpty()) {
    val stationTypesMap = mutableMapOf<StationType, ChargingEntityStatus>()

    stations.forEach {
        if (stationTypesMap.contains(it.type)) {
            val oldStatus = stationTypesMap[it.type] ?: ChargingEntityStatus.UNAVAILABLE
            val newStatus = it.status
            if (oldStatus.ordinal >= newStatus.ordinal) {
                stationTypesMap[it.type] = newStatus
            }
        } else {
            stationTypesMap[it.type] = it.status
        }
    }

    val (available, unavailable) = stationTypesMap.entries
            .partition { it.value == ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE }

    // then I'll be working with these two lists
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but instead of a mutable map, which should have O(logn) lookups, you could use a lookup table with O(1) lookups. Convert the types to indexes of an array and store the best statuses for each at the respective indexes in that array. That way you can also remove the ```.contains``` if statement, since each type already has a position in the list. A very minor improvement, but an improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```kotlin
enum class StationType {
    TYPE_1,
    TYPE_2,
    FAST,
}

enum class ChargingEntityStatus {
    UNAVAILABLE, // the worst option
    RESERVED,
    CHARGING,
    AVAILABLE, // the best option
    OCCUPIED
}

data class Station(
    val stationId: Long,
    val type: StationType,
    val status: ChargingEntityStatus,
)

fun main(){
    val temp = listOf(
        Station(1, StationType.TYPE_1, ChargingEntityStatus.CHARGING),
        Station(9, StationType.TYPE_2, ChargingEntityStatus.UNAVAILABLE),
        Station(3, StationType.TYPE_1, ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE),
        Station(7, StationType.FAST, ChargingEntityStatus.AVAILABLE)
    )
    val filteredList = temp
        .sortedByDescending { it.status }
        .distinctBy { it.type }
        .sortedByDescending { it.stationId }
        .reversed()
        .toList()
    println(filteredList)
}
```

The main part is :

```
val filteredList = temp
   .sortedByDescending { it.status }
   .distinctBy { it.type }
   .sortedByDescending { it.stationId }
   .reversed()
   .toList()
```

First of all, I sorted with the status. So the best status option will come first by `.sortedByDescending { it.status }`. And I wanted to remove duplicated station type, so I used `distinctBy` method. As it was sorted with the status, the low priority object will be removed. Lastly, I sorted with stationId and reversed it to make it ascending order by station id. And as you wanted as list, I added `toList()` method. 
I also wanted to reduce the time complexity, so I reversed the `ChargingEntityStatus` enum class.

Comment: This is interesting, perfect use of Kotlin's power. I'd like to ask how you figure out what functions to use like that

Comment: @gtxtreme At first, I found it through auto code completion of Intellij IDE and google. I think I'm getting used to it everytime I use the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a `Map<StationType, Station>` and merge any two stations having same `StationType` based on the `ordinal` of `status`. for this you can define an extension function as

```
/**
 * Generates a map where keys are given by keyMapper and values are given by valueMapper.
 * If any two elements would have the same key returned by [keyMapper]
 * then merge function is used to merge the values of such keys.
 * T: type of Iterable elements
 * K: type of keys
 * R: type of values
 *
 * @return Map<K,R>
 */
private inline fun <T, K, R> Iterable<T>.toMapWithMerge(
        crossinline keyMapper: (T) -> K,
        valueMapper: (T) -> R,
        merge: (R, R) -> R
): Map<K, R>{
    return groupingBy(keyMapper).aggregate { key, accumulator: R?, element, first ->
        if(accumulator == null) valueMapper(element)
        else merge(accumulator, valueMapper(element))
    }
}
```

Now you can get your desired result as

```
val updatedList = originalList.toMapWithMerge({ it.type }, { it }, { s1, s2 ->
    // If two stations have same type then pick the one with lower ordinal. (as you define best)
    if (s1.status.ordinal < s2.status.ordinal) s1
    else s2
}).values.toList()
```